# Primeng Pie chart not displaying

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to display pie chart in my dashboard screen.
Followed the example in primefaces website. But it is not working. 
Below is my code. Please let me know whether i am missing any imports.

**app.module.ts**

```
   import {ChartModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

    @NgModule({
    --
    --
    imports: [
    --
    --
    ChartModule
```

**component.ts**

```
  piedata: any;


 ngOnInit() {

  this.piedata = {
            labels: ['A','B','C'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    piedata: [300, 50, 100],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "#FF6384",
                        "#36A2EB",
                        "#FFCE56"
                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                        "#FF6384",
                        "#36A2EB",
                        "#FFCE56"
                    ]
                }]
            };
}
```

**Html page**

```
<p-chart type="pie" [data]="piedata"></p-chart>
```

** Output **

[image]

Comment: Did you import primeng css? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need chart.js for it to function.do

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

and include that in your angular-cli.json file

```
"scripts": [
 "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
 //..others
 ],
```

Hope this helps

**Update:** Try this

```
 ngOnInit() {

  this.piedata = {
            labels: ['A','B','C'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [300, 50, 100],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "#FF6384",
                        "#36A2EB",
                        "#FFCE56"
                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                        "#FF6384",
                        "#36A2EB",
                        "#FFCE56"
                    ]
                }]
            };
}
```

Comment: Pie chart is not displaying.But pie chart labels are displaying with black strike mark

Comment: only pie chart or any chart??

Comment: Only pie chart.

Comment: Wth, why is it not mentioned anywhere on the documentation?

Comment: They have https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chart